# Is it better to use ElasticSearch as service or running it directly?

Tags: elasticsearch, service

On our website we use ElasticSearch (it is irrelevant for what exact purpose we use it, I'm not going into details about this). Is it better to use it as service or just having it run in the console?

Comment: installing as a service will be good option

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Definitely better as a service. It automatically starts at startup and you don't need to start it at all. You can set it up for automatic start in Linux. You can probably set it to restart if it crashes, using batch commands too.

Answer (score -1):

I feel it is better to run it as a service. It will help it to run in the background or start automatically at startup without any user interaction.

Comment: Yeah, but then it is the same if it crashes, I would have to restart it, just as I would have to restart it if it is just run regularly in command prompt.

Comment: You can use commands to do the restart if it crashes.